# Applications that use Node.js

Tags: node.js

Does someone knows several apps that currently use Node.js?,

I'm trying to create a Node.js community with some friends at my campus but I need some good real life examples to show and attract more people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot.

http://techcrunch.com/2010/09/01/nodejs-knockout/

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Projects,-Applications,-and-Companies-Using-Node